# Get Dependent Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a database application using EntityFramework 6 and SQL Server.
In case of deleting an entity. I would like to show the user every dependent entity that will get deleted with the selected one corresponding to the ON DELETE constraints. Before actually deleting it.

So my question is:

Are there any lightweight possibilities using EntityFramework or maybe using SQL Server specific queries directly to get them?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How comfortable are you with system tables like `sys.foreign_keys` and writing raw SQL queries?

Comment: Not that comfortable, but i am willing to learn. So sys.foreign keys will show me all Foreign Keys. Now i would need the particular entities that are "connected" by this FKs. Right? Is there another system table?

Comment: Yes. You see where I am going with this. Your table might be the parent or the child table. So you would probably need two queries.  I'll post some example SQL below.

Comment: How about this https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.dataclasses.relationshipmanager.getallrelatedends?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Objects_DataClasses_RelationshipManager_GetAllRelatedEnds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found a working solution for my problem. Just in case somebody else is interested. I will post this here. Its based on the comment from Eldho. You can get out the dependent objects using the Entity Framework. As said the RelationshipManager holds all dependent objects already.

I have written two Extension Methods for the DbContext: One to get all entities relying on the given entity. And one to get all entities the given entity relies on.

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
/// <summary>
/// Gets all entities the given entity is relying on.
/// Will cast the result to a given Type (Entity Base Class / Interface, whatever)
/// </summary>
public static List<TEntity> GetAllDependentEntities<TEntity>(this DbContext ctx, TEntity entity)
  where TEntity : class
{
  return ctx.GetAllRelatedEntities(entity, IsRelationshipParent);
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets all Entities relying on the given entity
/// Will cast the result to a given Type (Entity Base Class / Interface, whatever)
/// </summary>
public static List<TEntity> GetAllEntitiesDependingOn<TEntity>(this DbContext ctx, TEntity entity)
  where TEntity : class
{
  return ctx.GetAllRelatedEntities(entity, IsRelationshipChild);
}

private static List<TEntity> GetAllRelatedEntities<TEntity>(this DbContext ctx, TEntity entity, Func<IRelatedEnd, bool> relationshipFilter)
  where TEntity : class
{
  var result = new List<TEntity>();

  var queue = new Queue<TEntity>();
  queue.Enqueue(entity);

  while (queue.Any())
  {
    var current = queue.Dequeue();

    var foundDependencies = ctx.GetRelatedEntitiesFrom<TEntity>(current, relationshipFilter);
    foreach (var dependency in foundDependencies)
    {
      if (!result.Contains(dependency))
        queue.Enqueue(dependency);
    }

    result.Add(current);
  }

  return result;
}


private static List<TEntity> GetRelatedEntitiesFrom<TEntity>(this DbContext ctx, object entity, Func<IRelatedEnd, bool> relationshipFilter)
  where TEntity : class
{
  var stateManager = (ctx as IObjectContextAdapter)?.ObjectContext?.ObjectStateManager;

  if (stateManager == null)
    return new List<TEntity>();

  if (!stateManager.TryGetRelationshipManager(entity, out var relationshipManager))
    return new List<TEntity>();

  return relationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds()
                            .Where(relationshipFilter)
                            .SelectMany(ExtractValues<TEntity>)
                            .Where(x => x != null)
                            .ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<TEntity> ExtractValues<TEntity>(IRelatedEnd relatedEnd)
  where TEntity : class
{
  if (!relatedEnd.IsLoaded)
    relatedEnd.Load();

  if (relatedEnd is IEnumerable enumerable)
    return ExtractCollection<TEntity>(enumerable);
  else
    return ExtractSingle<TEntity>(relatedEnd);
}

private static IEnumerable<TEntity> ExtractSingle<TEntity>(IRelatedEnd relatedEnd)
  where TEntity : class
{
  var valueProp = relatedEnd.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
  var value = valueProp?.GetValue(relatedEnd);

  yield return value as TEntity;
}

private static IEnumerable<TEntity> ExtractCollection<TEntity>(IEnumerable enumerable)
{
  return enumerable.OfType<TEntity>();
}

private static bool IsRelationshipParent(IRelatedEnd relatedEnd)
  => relatedEnd.SourceRoleName.Contains("Target");

private static bool IsRelationshipChild(IRelatedEnd relatedEnd)
  => relatedEnd.TargetRoleName.Contains("Target");
}
```

or see here: https://gist.github.com/felixalmesberger/8a9fde392698e366d5cbb75853efb412

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you what you are looking for. In my example, I am finding all tables related to my table "Customers".

```
SELECT ParentTable.Name AS ParentTable, ChildTable.Name AS ChildTable
FROM sys.foreign_keys FK 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ParentTable ON FK.parent_object_id = ParentTable.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ChildTable ON FK.referenced_object_id = ChildTable.object_id
WHERE ParentTable.Name = 'Customers'
UNION
SELECT ParentTable.Name AS ParentTable, ChildTable.Name AS ChildTable
FROM sys.foreign_keys FK 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ParentTable ON FK.parent_object_id = ParentTable.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ChildTable ON FK.referenced_object_id = ChildTable.object_id
WHERE ChildTable.Name = 'Customers'
```

If you don't want to paste all of that SQL into your solution, you could just make that query into a View

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.RelatedTables
AS
SELECT ParentTable.Name AS ParentTable, ChildTable.Name AS ChildTable
FROM sys.foreign_keys FK 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ParentTable ON FK.parent_object_id = ParentTable.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ChildTable ON FK.referenced_object_id = ChildTable.object_id
```

Then query your VIEW like a table:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.RelatedTables 
WHERE ParentTable = 'Customers' OR ChildTable = 'Customers'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is definitly going into the right direction. I will now need to find all the entities related to one 'Customer' for example. I thought maybe there is another table where not the table relations are shown but the direct entity relations instead. But i think this is not the case. So i will have to work with that.