# EF Core 6: Given a primary key, find all related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core 6, and I want to:
Given a primary key, find all related entities.
Because:
When you try to delete an entity with EF Core, you'll get a DbUpdateException if other entities are dependent on it.
So I'd like to be able to list all the entities, that are dependent on a given primary key.
So I can present the user with valuable information about why the deletion operation failed. And they could go and delete the dependent entities or take some other action.
I've spend days trying to figure this out, and no other StackOverflow post covers this for EF Core (Did find one for the old EF).
Thanks in advance

Comment: *Did find one for the old EF*, which one?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908832/get-dependent-entities

Comment: Strange solution. Will take care about that tomorrow. How do you plan to get result of related entities? `List<object>`?

Comment: You will make my day if you could do something! That is actually a good question. Because then I would have to try cast against every object in my domain. My first thought was just Id, Type and Name for each, but not every entity is guaranteed to have a name prop.
Or maybe it's fine to get List<object> and cast, but the thing is, I would have to come back and expand this method each time I add a new domain model, but maybe that's fine.

Comment: Well, better to decide API for function. I propose the following `public static List<object> GetRelated<T>(IQueryable<T> query, DbContext context)`. Context is needed to get Model metadata information.  `query` can be any `IQueryable` with filter.

Comment: That would be great. What about `Guid primaryKey` in the argument list? In your API `T` would be type of the delete item, right? Because when I catch the `DbUpdateException` in `override SaveChangesAsync` in the base dbContext class, I only get Id from the exception. Then I would need to find out what type it is based on it's Id. Or maybe I could use `ChangeTracker` to get the type of object

Comment: Probably, it is needed just Entries which have state `Deleted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is my solution. Check which methods are missed. There are several overloads based on `GetDependedDataFromEntriesAsync`, which retrieves dependency information from any Queryable.

```cs
var dependencides = await context.MyEntities.Where(e => e.Id == 10)
   .GetDependedDataFromEntriesAsync(context);
```

Function generates `Include` query which in one roundtrip retrieves related data from database and collects into list of `DependencyInfo`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace EFHelpers
{
    public static class ContextExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns DependencyInfo for deleted entities without duplicates. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="maxDepth"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task<List<DependencyInfo>> GetDependedDeletedEntriesAsync(this DbContext context, int maxDepth = 10)
        {
            var dependency = await GetDependencyInformationFromEntries(context, context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted), maxDepth);

            var enrichedWithEntry = dependency.Select(d => new { Entry = context.Entry(d.Entity), Dependency = d });

            enrichedWithEntry = enrichedWithEntry.Where(x => x.Entry.State != EntityState.Deleted);

            // get only unique entries with shortest path
            var result = enrichedWithEntry
                .GroupBy(e => e.Entry)
                .Select(g => g.OrderBy(d => d.Dependency.Path.Length).Select(d => d.Dependency).First())
                .ToList();

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns depended entries without duplicates. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="untypedEntries"></param>
        /// <param name="maxDepth"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task<List<EntityEntry>> GetDependedEntriesFromEntries(DbContext context,
            IEnumerable<EntityEntry> untypedEntries, int maxDepth = 10)
        {
            var dependencies = await GetDependencyInformationFromEntries(context, untypedEntries, maxDepth);

            var result = dependencies.Select(d => context.Entry(d.Entity))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Collects DependencyInfo for any collection of entries
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="untypedEntries"></param>
        /// <param name="maxDepth"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task<List<DependencyInfo>> GetDependencyInformationFromEntries(DbContext context, IEnumerable<EntityEntry> untypedEntries, int maxDepth = 10)
        {
            var byType = untypedEntries.GroupBy(d => d.Entity.GetType())
                .Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Entries = g.ToList() })
                .ToList();

            var dependencies = new List<DependencyInfo>();

            foreach (var r in byType)
            {
                var task = (Task)_getDependedDataFromEntriesAsync.MakeGenericMethod(r.Type).Invoke(null, new object[] { context, r.Entries, maxDepth })!;
                await task;

                dynamic tasWithResult = task;

                dependencies.AddRange((List<DependencyInfo>)tasWithResult.Result);
            }

            return dependencies;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appends Includes to the source query and retrieves DependencyInfo
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="query"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="maxDepth"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
        public static async Task<List<DependencyInfo>> GetDependencyInformationFromQueryAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DbContext context, int maxDepth = 10)
            where T : class
        {
            var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
            if (entityType == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            var dependedNavigations = GetDependedNavigations(entityType).ToList();

            var includes = new List<string>();
            foreach (var navigation in dependedNavigations)
            {
                includes.AddRange(GenerateInclude(string.Empty, navigation, maxDepth));
            }

            var result = new List<DependencyInfo>();

            if (includes.Count == 0)
                return result;

            var queryWithIncludes = query;
            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                queryWithIncludes = queryWithIncludes.Include(include);
            }

            var loadedRecords = await queryWithIncludes.AsSplitQuery().ToListAsync();

            if (loadedRecords.Count > 0)
            {
                var pk = entityType.FindPrimaryKey() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

                var related = new List<(DependencyPath[] path, object entity)>();
                foreach (var record in loadedRecords)
                {
                    related.Clear();

                    var entry = context.Entry(record);

                    foreach (var navigation in dependedNavigations)
                    {
                        CollectDependedObjects(context, Array.Empty<DependencyPath>(), navigation, entry, related, maxDepth);
                    }

                    // Currently we do not care about composite keys
                    var key = GetPrimaryKeyValue(context.Entry(record));

                    result.AddRange(related.Select(r => new DependencyInfo(r.path, key, record, r.entity)));
                }

                // removing duplicates, leaving only shortest path
                result = result
                    .GroupBy(d => d.Entity)
                    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(d => d.Path.Length).First())
                    .ToList();
            }           

            return result;
        }

        private static Task<List<DependencyInfo>> GetDependedDataFromEntriesAsync<TEntity>(DbContext context,
            IEnumerable<EntityEntry> untypedEntries, int maxDepth)
            where TEntity: class
        {
            var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
            if (entityType == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            var pk = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();

            if (pk == null)
                return Task.FromResult(new List<DependencyInfo>());

            var entries = untypedEntries.Select(e => context.Entry((TEntity)e.Entity));

            var query = context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

            if (pk.Properties.Count == 1)
            {
                var pkProperty = pk.Properties[0];
                query = (IQueryable<TEntity>)_filterByProperty.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity), pkProperty.ClrType)
                    .Invoke(null, new object[] { query, entries, pkProperty })!;
            }
            else
            {
                query = (IQueryable<TEntity>)_filterByProperties.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity))
                    .Invoke(null, new object[] { query, entries, pk.Properties })!;
            }

            return GetDependencyInformationFromQueryAsync(query, context, maxDepth);
        }

        private static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterByProperty<TEntity, TValue>(IQueryable<TEntity> query, IEnumerable<EntityEntry<TEntity>> entries, IProperty property)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            // Extract values from entries
            var keys = entries.Select(e => e.CurrentValues.GetValue<TValue>(property))
                .ToList();

            var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntity).Name.Substring(1, 1).ToLower());

            // e => keys.Contains(e.PropName)
            var predicate =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                    Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains),
                        new[] { typeof(TValue) }, Expression.Constant(keys),
                        GetPropertyExpression(entityParam, property)),
                    entityParam);

            return query.Where(predicate);
        }

        private static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterByProperties<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query, IEnumerable<EntityEntry<TEntity>> entries,
            IReadOnlyList<IProperty> properties) 
            where TEntity : class
        {
            if (properties.Count == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Expected not empty", nameof(properties));

            var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntity).Name.Substring(1, 1).ToLower());

            Expression? predicate = null;

            var propExpressions = properties.Select(p => GetPropertyExpression(entityParam, p))
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                var values = properties.Select(p => entry.Properties.Single(pe => pe.Metadata == p).CurrentValue)
                    .ToList();

                Expression? combinedCondition = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < propExpressions.Length; ++i)
                {
                    var condition = Expression.Equal(propExpressions[i], Expression.Constant(values[i]));
                    combinedCondition = combinedCondition == null ? condition : Expression.AndAlso(combinedCondition, condition);
                }

                predicate = predicate == null ? combinedCondition : Expression.OrElse(predicate, combinedCondition!);
            }

            predicate ??= Expression.Constant(false);

            var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, entityParam);

            return query.Where(predicateLambda);
        }


        private static Expression GetPropertyExpression(Expression objExpression, IProperty property)
        {
            Expression propExpression;
            if (property.PropertyInfo == null)
            {
                // 'property' is Shadow property, so call via EF.Property(e, "name")
                propExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { property.ClrType },
                    objExpression, Expression.Constant(property.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                propExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(objExpression, property.PropertyInfo);
            }

            return propExpression;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GenerateInclude(string prevPath, INavigation navigation, int depth)
        {
            if (depth == 0)
                yield break;

            var path = navigation.Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prevPath))
                path = prevPath + "." + path;

            var found = false;

            foreach (var include in GetDependedNavigations(navigation.TargetEntityType).SelectMany(n => GenerateInclude(path, n, depth - 1)))
            {
                found = true;
                yield return include;
            }

            if (!found)
                yield return path;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<INavigation> GetDependedNavigations(IEntityType entityType)
        {
            return entityType.GetNavigations().Where(n => !n.IsOnDependent);
        }

        private static void AddDependedObject(DbContext context, DependencyPath[] prevPath, INavigation navigation, object obj, List<(DependencyPath[] path, object entity)> related, int depth)
        {
            var entry = context.Entry(obj);

            var path = new[] { new DependencyPath(navigation.Name, GetPrimaryKeyValue(entry)) };

            if (prevPath.Length > 0)
            {
                path = prevPath.Concat(path).ToArray();
            }

            related.Add((path, obj));

            if (depth > 0)
            {
                foreach (var n in GetDependedNavigations(navigation.TargetEntityType))
                {
                    CollectDependedObjects(context, path, n, entry, related, depth - 1); 
                }
            }
        }

        private static object? GetEntryPropertyValue(EntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase property)
        {
            return entry.Properties.Single(ep => ep.Metadata == property).CurrentValue;
        }

        private static object? GetPrimaryKeyValue(EntityEntry entry)
        {
            var pk = entry.Metadata.FindPrimaryKey();
            if (pk == null)
                return null;

            if (pk.Properties.Count == 1)
            {
                return GetEntryPropertyValue(entry, pk.Properties[0]);
            }

            return pk.Properties.Select(p => GetEntryPropertyValue(entry, p)).ToArray();
        }

        private static void CollectDependedObjects(DbContext context, DependencyPath[] prevPath, INavigation navigation, EntityEntry entry, List<(DependencyPath[] path, object entity)> related,
            int depth)
        {
            if (depth == 0)
                return;

            var value = navigation.GetGetter().GetClrValue(entry.Entity);

            if (navigation.IsCollection)
            {
                if (value is IEnumerable collection)
                {
                    foreach (var obj in collection)
                    {
                        if (obj != null)
                            AddDependedObject(context, prevPath, navigation, obj, related, depth - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    AddDependedObject(context, prevPath, navigation, value, related, depth - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        public class DependencyInfo
        {
            public DependencyInfo(DependencyPath[] path, object? rootKey, object rootEntity, object entity)
            {
                Path = path;
                RootKey = rootKey;
                RootEntity = rootEntity;
                Entity = entity;
            }

            public DependencyPath[] Path { get; }
            public object? RootKey { get; }
            public object RootEntity { get; }
            public object Entity { get; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{RootEntity.GetType().Name}[{RootKey}].{string.Join('.', Path.Select(p => p.ToString()))}: {Entity.GetType().Name}";
            }
        }

        public class DependencyPath
        {
            public DependencyPath(string name, object? key)
            {
                Name = name;
                Key = key;
            }

            public string Name { get; }
            public object? Key{ get; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                var key = Key;
                if (key is Array array)
                {
                    key = "[" + string.Join(',', array.Cast<object>().Select(e => e.ToString())) + "]";
                }
                return $"({key}){Name}";
            }
        }

        private static MethodInfo _getDependedDataFromEntriesAsync =
            typeof(ContextExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(GetDependedDataFromEntriesAsync), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static) ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Method '{nameof(GetDependedDataFromEntriesAsync)}' not found.");

        private static MethodInfo _filterByProperty =
            typeof(ContextExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(FilterByProperty), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static) ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Method '{nameof(FilterByProperty)}' not found.");

        private static MethodInfo _filterByProperties =
            typeof(ContextExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(FilterByProperties), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static) ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Method '{nameof(FilterByProperties)}' not found.");

    }
}
```

Comment: You went above and beyond with this answer! But I realize I (kinda) asked the wrong question. This will give me the entities that depends on this, but what I need is the entites this entity depend on. (The other way around).
I am deleting a `Language` that is assigned to a `Organization`, and get DbUpdateException, and would like to say: "You cannot delete this language [RUSSIAN] because [ORGANIZATION NAME] is dependent on it.

Comment: Actually it is should return exactly this information. Set MaxDepth = 1

Comment: I tried all your methods with maxDepth = 1 or and more, but I only get empty lists

Comment: Check that `GetDependedNavigations` returns needed properties.

Comment: `GetDependedNavigations` returns an empty list with all of the public methods. In your example on how to use it:
`var dependencides = await context.MyEntities.Where(e => e.Id == 10)
   .GetDependedDataFromEntriesAsync(context);`
It seems the collection is known, you called it "MyEntities". But I want to pass an entity and then get all the dependents, I don't know what the current type is. Sometimes I try to delete a product, and like to know what menucard it's dependent on, sometimes I try to delete a language, but an organization uses that language so I can't delete it.

Comment: Try to remove `.Where(n => !n.IsOnDependent)`

Comment: They still all return an empty list :/

Comment: How it can be? Does your classes have navigation properties?

Comment: On `Organization` I have `public SystemLanguage DefaultLanguage { get; set; }`. Now I tried to add `public Guid DefaultLanguageId { get; set; }` as well, but now an `Organization` will be deleted without further notice, when a `SystemLanguage` is deleted, which I also don't want

Comment: Then `entityType.GetNavigations()` should return at least one navigation.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to use navigation properties, so that you can you can use the "Include" extension method to eager load all related objects. Or you can use the cascade delete to trace and delete all related items along its parent

Comment: I cannot use "Include" since I don't know the entity type in question. I want a generic method that takes a primary key, and lists all dependent entities on that primary key. So I can tell the user: You cannot delete this Restaurant [NAME] because it is dependend on Location [NAME]