# Find foreign key references in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The short version:

Is there a way to ask Entity Framework Core 7 (EF Core 7) if a generic entity has any Foreign Key (FK) references? Put another way, is there a way to ask EF Core 7 if deleting an entity would fail due to an FK reference violation (assuming all FK references are NOT *cascade deletes*)?

The long version:

I have a website that sells widgets. The website contains a SQL database and uses EF Core 7 to access the database.

The database contains several tables that contain information about things that don't change often, such as widget descriptions, tax schedules, etc. These tables are referenced by many other tables (orders, shipping, product support, etc.). Thus, rows in these "don't change very often" tables *cannot be deleted* if any of the other tables (orders, shipping, etc.) have FK references to them. Put another way, you can't delete a widget if the shipping table thinks that that type of widget is on a truck heading to Omaha.

When I want to update my list of widgets (or my tax schedules, or any of the "don't change very often" tables), I call a generic function that accepts the up-to-date List of generic entities, and updates the database, adding, updating, or deleting items in the database as necessary.

```
public async Task UpdateDatabase<TEntity>(List<TEntity> newItems)
    where TEntity : IEntityInfo, class
{
    <...>
}
```

This routine pulls the existing `TEntity` items from the database, compares them (actually, compares the properties exposed by the `IEntityInfo` interface) with the `newItems` list, and adds, modifies, or removes items from the database.

Adding or modifying items is easy. But *removing* items is problematic. If an existing item (i.e. a tracked entity mapped to a row in the database) has any FK references, deleting the item from the `DbContext` will fail with a `DbUpdateException` when `UpdateDatabase()` is called. At that point, the item is *removed* (`EntityState.Deleted`) in the `DbContext`, but it still exists in the database. And any further calls to `UpdateDatabase` will fail.

So, **I'm looking for a way to determine whether a generic entity can be deleted** (i.e. whether the entity has any FK references). (And before someone asks about cascade deletes, the database design is such that all FK references are *restricted deletes*. In other words, you can't delete a widget if it's on a truck to Omaha, or if some customer has that type of widget in an order.)

The above routine doesn't know anything about the connections between the generic entities that it is given to work with and the rest of the database. It would seem that I have two options:

1. My preferred option: Ask EF Core if the generic entity has any FK references. I don't think this is possible, but it's worth writing this *long* post to see if someone has a brilliant suggestion.
2. Have `IEntityInfo` include a `CanBeDeleted()` method. Thus, each entity class can implement its own logic to determine whether or not it can be deleted. The problem with this approach is that it's very fragile. `CanBeDeleted()` needs to know about every FK in the database that might prevent the item's deletion; this method must be updated any time a new FK reference to the entity is added to the database design.

Comment: Even you know that entity has a FK, you still need to check there is any related record for the FK. What I think is catch the exception which if there is an exception for that in the catch block do what you need. If you just want to check is there any FK for the table I think you can get it from database. For me I use EF to create table then delete all FK but my DB is PostgresSQL

Comment: Check this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250466/10646316) It collect depended entities and loads them if needed.

Comment: The current code, which kind of worked in EF6 but no longer works in EF7, caught the exception then tried to clean up the DbContext by setting removed entries back to unchanged (and setting added entries to disconnected and modified entries to their original values). This approach appeared to work, although I suspect it was super fragile. But with EF 7, if I continue to use the DbContext after I catch the exception and clean up the DbContext state, I get wacky errors. Entity properties magically change values; trying to commit changes throws concurrency exceptions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks! My problem is much simpler than that the one addressed by [your excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250466/10646316). I don't need to know what the foreign references are, only if any exist (since any FK reference will prevent deletion). But I can use your code as a guide to what is possible.

Comment: I can create such generic function. What is needed - sample model.

Comment: `public static async Task<bool> HasFkReferenceAsync<T>(this DbContext db, T entity)` returns `true` if `entity` currently has any foreign key references (from rows in other tables in the database).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I said (above) that I want to detect if the entity has ANY Foreign Key references. That works for my design because I know that all foreign keys are "restricted" deletes. But if you are writing a routine to solve my problem (thank you!) then you probably want to solve a more generic problem that other users would find useful: Name the routine CanDeleteAsync, and filter the FK properties that you check to exclude any whose `DeleteBehavior` is "cascade delete" (i.e., FKs that would not prevent deletion).

Comment: It would be more performant if function will accept list of entities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250171/discussion-between-bob-at-indigo-health-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).